# If else statement php/js/jquery (Radio buttons and textfields)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, radio-button, textfield

I am using the code as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/t6noeL9q/1/

I want to use the if else statement in php. For example, if I choose radio button 1 and enter the rate of severity, a recommendation should be displayed in recommendation 1 textfield. The recommendations should change on varying the the probability and severity. How can I do this?

Code:

```
<div class="radio">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" style="background:white; border-style:none; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px; " type="text" name="q1" readonly='true' value="No security of hardware" />
    </td>

<p>
</p>
    <td>
      Rare &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Rare">
    </td>
    <td>
      Unlikely &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Unlikely">
    </td>
    <td>
      Moderate &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Moderate">
    </td>
    <td>
      Likely &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Likely">
    </td>
    <td>
      Very Likely &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Very Likely">
    </td>
    <br>
    <td>
      Severity(Rate 1-10)&nbsp;<input style="width:50px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="severity1" />
    </td>
</div>
</tr>

<br>


<tr>
  <div class="radio">
    <tr>
      <td>
      <br>
        <input class="form-control" style="background:white; border-style:none; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px; " type="text" name="q2" readonly='true' value="No security in access control to systems" />
      </td>

      <td>
        Rare &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Rare">
      </td>
      <td>
        Unlikely &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Unlikely">
      </td>
      <td>
        Moderate &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Moderate">
      </td>
      <td>
        Likely &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Likely">
      </td>
      <td>
        Very Likely &nbsp;<input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Very Likely">
      </td>
      <td>
        Severity(Rate 1-10)&nbsp;<input style="width:50px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="severity2" />
      </td>

  </div>
  </tr>

  <div class="radio">
    <tr>
      <td>
      <br>
      <br>
Recommendation1: <input type="text" name="r1"/> <br><br>
Recommendation2: <input type="text" name="r2"/>
```

Comment: You can't use php in client mode (http browser). To do this use js/jQuery. php is a server-side language: it doesn't directly interact with browser actions.

Comment: how can I do this? Please find the link to the code above in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If the `if` statement has to be in PHP, you can either create a form and pass it to a new PHP script, or (more preferable way) you can use AJAX and JQUERY to pass the state of radio buttons to a PHP script and retrieve its output. The second solution allows you to display the result without reloading the page.
However this is not how you should do it. The proper way to solve this problem is to write a function in javascript which would check the state of the radio buttons and display the result dynamically instead of using PHP. I've written a simple code snippet to show you how to do it (I'm trying to avoid the XY problem by providing a solution which will more likely address your actual problem).

Of course if you need to do some server-side computation, then the AJAX / POST methods, which I described, are unavoidable.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function display_result(radio_value, text_value){
    switch(radio_value){
      case "Rare":{
        /*do stuff*/
        break;
      }
      case "Unlikely":{
        /*do some other stuff*/
        break;
      }
      /* etc. */
    }
    alert(radio_value + " " + text_value); //Just to show you that it's working
  }
  $("#row1 input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    display_result($(this).val(), $("#row1 [name=severity1]").val());
  });
  $("#row1 [name=severity1]").change(function(){
    display_result($("#row1 input[type=radio]:checked").val(), $(this).val());
  });
  $("#row2 input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    display_result($(this).val(), $("#row2 [name=severity2]").val());
  });
  $("#row2 [name=severity2]").change(function(){
    display_result($("#row2 input[type=radio]:checked").val(), $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio" id="row1">

  <tr>
    <td>
      <h5><b>Physical Security</b></h5></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" style="background:white; border-style:none; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px; " type="text" name="q1" readonly='true' value="No security of computer equipment" />
    </td>


    <td>
      <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Rare">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Unlikely">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Moderate">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Likely">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad1[]" value="Very Likely">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="width:50px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="severity1" />
    </td>
</div>
</tr>



<tr>
  <div class="radio" id="row2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" style="background:white; border-style:none; box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px; " type="text" name="q2" readonly='true' value="No security in access control to systems" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Rare">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Unlikely">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Moderate">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Likely">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="margin-left:-2px;" type="radio" name="rad2[]" value="Very Likely">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="width:50px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="severity2" />
      </td>

  </div>
  </tr>

  <div class="radio">
    <tr>
      <td>
```

Comment: I do not have to display message box. I need to display the appropriate recommendation based on the probability and severity.

Comment: As I said in the comment - the message box is just to show you that the function is receiving the proper data. You can do whatever you want with the data in the switch statement. Do you want me to write the rest of the code, which will fill a textfield based on the input (probability and severity)?